# Showing the loaded ServerLimit & MaxClients value from shell?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

Is there a command to show current (in ssh) loaded setting for those directive?

Apache2, debian6

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean other than cat the config file? I guess I don't understand the question.

Comment: @bah: yes. Just to know if apache got em right. Like mysql `SHOW VARIABLES '%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I in your apache have (and loaded) mod_info module, try to access http://localhost/server-info page.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -s http://localhost/server-status | grep requests | perl -wlne'm/dt>(.*)<\/dt/i && print $1'`
```